# How to use emacs as my JAVA IDE?

Tags: java, maven-2, emacs, ide

I would like to use emacs instead of Netbeans which gets too bloated on my computer. I already have JDEE, I did not dig it, but it looks like it lacks:

- Classes testing : run a class which has a main method, but which is not the main class of the project
- Maven integration : this is a minor wish as Netbeans doesn't support maven that well too.

Comment: As a note, NetBeans supports Maven pretty well in my opinion. I don't know why you're saying it doesn't.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent, short answer: pom.xml should be the unique configuration file in a maven project.

Comment: I don't understand the short answer.

Comment: what the use of having a separate configuration file called nbactions.xml when it can be in the pom.xml ? I use maven, for automatic dependency fetching & IDE agnosticism.

Comment: You don't need that file when using Maven with NetBeans. At least, I don't (and I'm well aware of Maven benefits).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I recommend you to use [malabar-mode](http://github.com/espenhw/malabar-mode) instead of JDEE - malabar is the only modern mode for Java development currently available for Emacs. It offers:

- Tight integration with Maven
- A Groovy console for rapid prototyping and exploratory programming
- JUnit integration, both for running tests standalone and through Maven
- Import help; import one class or all needed classes in the buffer (with prompting if the class name is ambiguous)
- Extend class / implement interface / override method helpers
- Simplistic refactorings

Comment: Does malabar-mode do code completion? If not what should I use to get code completion working for Java?

Comment: In does completion with semantic. You can add autocomplete-mode and use it semantic completion source to get even nicer completion.

Comment: I have this working. However, how does one get cedet/semantic to parse the imported classes for real completion of system classes?

Comment: It looks like the two projects will be/are merging: https://github.com/m0smith/malabar-mode#malabar-is-moving-to-jdee

Answer (score 3):

For Maven look to ede-proj-maven2 (inherited from ede-generic) in current CEDET from CVS.  It's simple, but does some job.  I plan to look to it in the near future, because I use Maven very often with Clojure.